# core data how to filter (NSPredicate) including a relationship requirement and given the relationship object?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, relationship, nspredicate

How would I filter (construct an NSPredicate) for the following.

- Have a SCHOOL and PERSON entities
- One-to-many relationship, i.e. a PERSON has one SCHOOL, SCHOOL has many PERSONs
- Input to the filter method are (a) persons Name (e.g. all with a first name of "Tom") , and (b) the managed object of the School itself.
- for the purposes of this question assume School has no unique attributes

So then my confusion/observations are:

- I already have the School managed object itself, however not sure how to use this when creating the predicate?
- But if I create the NSPredicate how do I create the relationship to the SCHOOL in any case, as there are no IDs (identifiers) linking them myself as I'm letting Core Data do this?

Preference is SWIFT (however if someone knows in Objective-C that might help me too).  So what I'm trying to do again is:

- Get all PERSON objects, for which first name = "xxx", and for which they are associated with the following SCHOOL managed object.

Comment: Have the schools unique names or any other unique property value? If yes, you could use that for the predicate.

Comment: Show example data and desired result with the code you tried so far and the error / results it produced

Comment: no unique names in SCHOOL currently - hoping there's a way to create such a predicate without having to do this...?

Comment: no code with errors to show, as I'm not sure how to construct the code

Comment: But how do you identify/distinguish the schools at all? You need that already while assigning a school to a person.

Comment: there is a title now, however it's not unique, noting that core data manages the relationship itself.    I could make it unique, but my question here is really how to perform a search/filter in core data as it is now?  Perhaps it's not possible?

Comment: perhaps it boils down as to whether you can include an managed object as one of the parameters when constructing an NSPredicate

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The predicate would be what you expect.

```
NSPredicate(format: "name = %@ && school = %@", "Tom", school)
```

However, you can get to the person without a predicate by using the relationship in the other direction and filter.

```
let tom = school.persons.filter { $0.name == "Tom" }.first
```

(You might have to cast your `NSSet` to `Set<Person>`).

Comment: Seems you picked the wrong answer. :-(. Avoiding the predicate is preferable.

Comment: oh, hadn't consider this - do you say this just because the code is simpler this way?  or is there something else?

Comment: Yes, much less code, more "Swift"-like, and you let Core Data handle the database layer while focusing on the object graph. You actually should not have to care about setting up fetch requests.

Comment: Think there's a small typo. The `filter` block should be `$0.name == "Tom"` (it is currently assigning `$0.name = "Tom"`).

Comment: @bauerMusic Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Unless there's something I'm missing, this is a pure-Swift solution that does not involve Core Data at all. You're simply faulting every single Person associated with the School into memory and then manually checking to see if each one matches the criteria. This is nearly always the wrong solution.

Comment: It would look like that, but the fact that you are filtering `NSManagedObject` will still create efficiencies. You can test this on 100.000 records without delays or memory spike.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming the following model:

[image]

.. *and* you want to use `NSPredicate` .. you could try something like:

```
func searchSchool(school: School, firstName: String) -> [Person] {

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Person")
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "school == %@ && firstName == %@", school, firstName)
    request.predicate = predicate

    // we will perform the request on the context associated with the School NSManagedObject
    guard let context = school.managedObjectContext else {
        print("provided School managed object is not associated with a managed object context")
        return []
    }

    do {
        return try context.executeFetchRequest(request) as? [Person] ?? []
    } catch {
        return []
    }

}
```

However, don't forget other options (like traversing the relationship and using `filter` as suggested by @Mundi)

Comment: many thanks - wasn't sure which answer I'm supposed to pick however noting your answer gave the entire context in code...

Comment: There is a mistake in the data model graph above (to-many in wrong direction). Also, the provided method is not suitable for display in a table (should be fetched results controller).

Comment: The model graph looks fine to me ... `School` can have *many* `Person`s (to-many, represented by the double end on arrow from `School` to `Person`); `Person` has *one* school (to-one, represented by single end on arrow from `Person` to `School`).  With the exact model above, the generated NSManagedObject subclasses are correct with NSSet for `persons` property in `School`.  I too am a big fan `NSFetchedResultsController` for tables pulling from CoreData.  No mention of using tables in the OP question.  Code was trying to help OP with an example.  Upvoted your answer so you won't feel cheated.